# Can we create interactive PDF forms using reportlab?

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

Can we create interactive PDF forms using reportlab?  That is, a form that takes in data from readers and save them into the database.

Comment: To clarify the question of what an interactive form is - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7dd2.w.html and this example http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Samples/interactiveform_enabled.pdf and yes, I need this too from reportlab ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by interactive PDF forms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

reportlab.pdfbase.pdfform.py implies that you can, but it doesn't sound like a mature feature.

```
Support for Acrobat Forms in ReportLab documents

This module is somewhat experimental at this time.

Includes basic support for
    textfields,
    select fields (drop down lists), and
    check buttons.

The public interface consists of functions at the moment.
At some later date these operations may be made into canvas
methods. (comments?)

The ...Absolute(...) functions position the fields with respect
to the absolute canvas coordinate space -- that is, they do not
respect any coordinate transforms in effect for the canvas.
```

Comment: Robin discussed the two frameworks recently on the Reportlab mailing list https://pairlist2.pair.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2020-October/012009.html